# Screen flickers during 3D gameplay on 15.10

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics, compiz, 15.10

So this is not the first time this has happened. I recently installed an Nvidia graphics card, but even before that the screen would flicker from time to time on the Intel HD graphics. Installing the card and the drivers only made it 10 times worse. I've tried installing compiz config and enabling "Force full screen redraws", that didn't work. It only happens after a short period of time playing a graphically intensive 3d game, and then it starts flickering every 2 seconds making any game unplayable. It never happens on the desktop. This has frustrated me to the point that I almost want to ditch Ubuntu and find a copy of Windows 7 (considering I just bought this card and I can't even really use it!). Could it be an overheating issue? Is there something else I can tweak in compiz to fix this? Could it be a wrong or incompatible driver?

For reference, my card is an ASUS GeForce GTX 750 Ti OC and the drivers were obtained via `sudo apt-get install nvidia-352`.

Comment: Possibly [this known bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/compiz/+bug/1307144). In compiz config, try unchecking *unredirect fullscreen windows* and see if it makes any difference.

Comment: @lemon         I tried toggling that, but it doesn't seem to work. I did it from console, where is the actual place I can uncheck or check it?

Answer (score 0):

Possibly [this known bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/compiz/+bug/1307144).

In compiz config, try unchecking *unredirect fullscreen windows* and see if it makes any difference. This can be done by opening CompizConfig Settings Manager and clicking on Composite and then the appropriate toggle. Also, go back and select OpenGL and make sure *Sync to VBlank* is enabled.

If that doesn't help, make sure page flipping is enabled: open nvidia-settings > OpenGL Settings, and enable "allow flipping".

Does increasing GPU performance reduce the flickering? In nvidia-settings under PowerMizer, set Preferred Mode to maximum.

Comment: Unfortunately, with all of these implemented, it still flickers.